# how to block text messages in android

Tags: android

How to block outgoing and incoming text messages in Android. any help closer to this question will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Do you mean block as in block sending or block receiving or making sure the phone doesn't show a notification, etc? I'm not sure any of that can be done.

Comment: I am blocking the Text sms here.. I managed to block the incomming call

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://www.forceclose.com/.